# Is it a good practice to synchronize Development and Production server environments for testing a social app?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, testing, load-testing

I'm working on an app in which users make content and interact with that content on a server. From time to time I make updates to the app, and I test these updates with beta testers on a development server.

The issue is that during testing, all of my beta testers will be forced to interact with only each other, as the server will be mostly empty compared to the rich production server that has thousands of users.

**Example of my issue using Facebook:** if Facebook was going to run a test with a development server, they would have to build a simulated & truncated data set and it wouldn't be the same as the real Facebook - so the beta testers would have a bad experience/wouldn't really be able to test properly.

*Is it a good practice to build a mechanism to mirror the production and development servers to each other during testing?*

*At some point do I just have to abandon the production/development testing format?*

Comment: If you abandon it, its so hard to get back and so painful when you dont have it.  The problem w/ a mirror from your prod to dev is that it slows down your prod machine.  Instead try doing a nightly snapshot of prod and restoring that to your dev/testing environ.  Also, check out [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) for better answers to these types of questions.

Comment: Yes, if it's feasible, copy production over to development/testing. I don't understand the "to each other" bit.

Comment: @MarcusAdams re "to each other": meaning if beta users manipulate some of the data, it should get recorded on the production environment as well. The mirroring would have to go both ways or else the beta tester wouldn't be *actually* interacting with friends on production environment.